# flutter (Dart) Method 'tr' Called at null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I got this flutter app works with two languages. Display items in menus well but when I try to edit and route to edit page it comes this error,
(I use add and edit at the same page route but the parameters are different) When I try to add the route works well without any errors but when I try to edit the app start giving me a lot of errors at console and (Method called at null) and point at the String text I want to localize.
I used EasyLocalization widget.

here the error and code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = EasyLocalizationProvider.of(context).data;
    return EasyLocalizationProvider (
        data: data,
        child: Scaffold (
            appBar: AppBar (
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).tr("Scan By Trip ID")),
            centerTitle: true,
        ),
```

and here the error :

```
_EmployeeScreenState#a9074):
I/flutter (10733): The method 'tr' was called on null.
I/flutter (10733): Receiver: null
I/flutter (10733): Tried calling: tr("Scan By Trip ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this to your material app:

```
MaterialApp(
 localizationsDelegates: [
   // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
 ],
 supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en'), // English
    const Locale('he'), // Hebrew
    const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh'), // Chinese *See Advanced Locales below*
    // ... other locales the app supports
  ],
  // ...
)
```

Comment: already have this code at my main material app ,, still got the same error !!!